# Why can position and velocity be measured with reticle ticks, when their unit of angular measure is unknown?

Tags: projectile

Abbreviate Reticle Ticks as RT. For simplicity, assume 3 below, and the simplest case: no air resistance, gravity, or recoil.

Why can RT be used to measure position and velocity? I.e., how does 1 imply 2 below? I'm astonished how we can deduce so much from RT; without knowing the RT's unit of angular measure; and when per 1, RT measures angle, and not length (e.g. metres).

> $\color{green}{\text{[1.]}}$ The great thing about reticle ticks is that they're actually measurements of angle. $\color{green}{\text{[End of 1.]}}$. Because of this, a lot of our aiming has very little to do with the calibration of the reticle, $\color{red}{\text{[2.]}}$ because we'll be measuring positions and velocities in terms of reticle ticks
>   $\color{green}{\text{[3.]}}$ (assuming that the reticle's ticks are evenly spaced).  $\color{green}{\text{[End of 3.]}}$
>
> Let $\vec{v}(t)=(v_x,v_y)$ be the apparent velocity of the target (in **reticle ticks/sec**). $\color{red}{\text{[End of 2.]}}$ The $z$ axis is parallel to the line of sight (positive direction points away from you), while the $x$ and $y$ axes are the horizontal and vertical crosshairs. Let the apparent position (in the reticle) of the object at the moment of firing be $(0,0)$. [...]

Comment: As the quote says, the ticks themselves are the units. I don't think it's implying that you can convert this alone to units like meters; rather, the ticks themselves are sufficient for the viewer's purpose.

Comment: What document are you quoting from? Please provide a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be two separate questions: Why can we work exclusively in angles, and why can we use RT as the units? I'll answer them separately.

**Why can we work exclusively in angles?**

To understand this, let's explore what it means to aim a gun. Aiming is simply pointing the gun in a certain direction. Pointing a gun in a certain direction is the same thing as rotating the gun by a certain angle. So, when you're aiming, your final answer for where to aim is an angle, meaning that it's easier to just ask, "How fast is the target's angle changing?" rather than asking, "How fast is the target's position changing?" and having to do a bunch of conversions at the end.

**Why can we use RT as a unit?**

Again, this has to do with the fact that your final answer for where to aim is in RT, so it's easier to do everything in units of RT, rather than convert from RT to something else and then back. I'll illustrate with an example.

If we insist on using standard angular units for the calculation:

Suppose you know that your RT have a spacing of 0.1 degrees between them. You spot an object 3 RT left and 1 RT above where you're currently pointing. You observe that it's moving at a speed of 1 RT right and 1 RT down per second. Converting this to degrees, the object is 0.3 degrees left and 0.1 degrees up, and moving at a speed of 0.1 degree right and 0.1 degree down per second. You know (from earlier calculations based on the target's distance and the bullet's velocity) that your bullet takes 1.5 seconds to reach the target. Therefore, it will have moved 0.15 degrees right and 0.15 degrees down, putting it at an angle of 0.15 degrees left and 0.05 degrees down from your current position. Converting back, this means you should aim at a point 1.5 RT left and 0.5 RT down from your current position.

If we use RT as angular units:

You spot an object 3 RT left and 1 RT above where you're currently pointing. You observe that it's moving at a speed of 1 RT right and 1 RT down per second. You know (from earlier calculations based on the target's distance and the bullet's velocity) that your bullet takes 1.5 seconds to reach the target. Therefore, it will have moved 1.5 RT right and 1.5 RT down, which means you should aim at a point 1.5 RT left and 0.5 RT down from your current position.

As you can see, conversion doesn't really do much to help you, as you must immediately convert back. All it does is make the calculation longer.